# Erro para imprimir na tela um nome em C, usando lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Eu fiz este código com o objetivo d pedir notas e nomes e depois imprimir na tela, so que por algum motivo o nome n esta sendo mostrando o nome q foi digitado.O codigo foi feito no C.

```
{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct ElementoLista{
    char nome[81];
    char matricula[8];
    char turma;
    float p1;
    float p2;
    float p3;
    struct ElementoLista*prox;
}ElementoLista;

typedef struct Lista{
    ElementoLista*inicio;
    ElementoLista*fim;
}Lista;

Lista*CriandoLista(){
Lista*lista;
lista=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
lista->inicio=NULL;
lista->fim=NULL;
return lista;
}

void CopiarString(char*origem,char*Destino){
    while(*origem!='\0'){
        *Destino=*origem;
         Destino++;origem++;
    }
    *Destino='\0';
}

ElementoLista*CriandoElemento(float p1,float p2,float p3,char*nome){
    ElementoLista*novo=(ElementoLista*)malloc(sizeof(ElementoLista));
    memset(novo,0,sizeof(ElementoLista));
    CopiarString(novo->nome,nome);
    novo->p1=p1;
    novo->p2=p2;
    novo->p3=p3;
    novo->prox=NULL;
    return novo;
}

void addElemento(Lista*lista,ElementoLista*novoElemento){
    if(lista->inicio==NULL){
        lista->fim=novoElemento;
        lista->inicio=novoElemento;
    }else{
        lista->fim->prox=novoElemento;
        novoElemento->prox=NULL;
        lista->fim=novoElemento;
    }
}

void Imprimir(Lista*lista){
    ElementoLista*aux=lista->inicio;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        printf("Nome Da Pessoa \n");
        for(int i=0;(aux->nome[i])!='\0';i++){
            printf("%c",aux->nome[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    printf("p1= ");
    printf("%f\n",aux->p1);

    printf("p2= ");
    printf("%f\n",aux->p2);

    printf("p3= ");
    printf("%f\n",aux->p3);
    aux=aux->prox;
    }
}

int main(){
    Lista*lista=CriandoLista();
    float a=1.2,b=1.5,c=5.6;
    char nome[81];
    printf("De o nome Da Pessoa ");
    scanf("%s",&nome);
    addElemento(lista,CriandoElemento(a,b,c,nome));
    Imprimir(lista);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veja se é isso que esta precisando. Você não passou a referência nome na função imprimir, e não esta usando a variável que você declarou para armazenar o nome do aluno.
     #include 
     #include 
     #include

```
typedef struct ElementoLista{
 char nome[81];
 char matricula[8];
 char turma;
 float p1;
 float p2;
 float p3;
 struct ElementoLista*prox;
}ElementoLista;

typedef struct Lista{
 ElementoLista*inicio;
 ElementoLista*fim;
}Lista;

Lista*CriandoLista(){
 Lista*lista;
 lista=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
 lista->inicio=NULL;
 lista->fim=NULL;
return lista;
}

void CopiarString(char*origem,char*Destino){
 while(*origem!='\0'){
     *Destino=*origem;
      Destino++;origem++;
 }
 *Destino='\0';
}

ElementoLista*CriandoElemento(float p1,float p2,float p3,char*nome){
 ElementoLista*novo=(ElementoLista*)malloc(sizeof(ElementoLista));
 memset(novo,0,sizeof(ElementoLista));
 CopiarString(novo->nome,nome);
 novo->p1=p1;
 novo->p2=p2;
 novo->p3=p3;
 novo->prox=NULL;
 return novo;
}

void addElemento(Lista*lista,ElementoLista*novoElemento){
 if(lista->inicio==NULL){
     lista->fim=novoElemento;
     lista->inicio=novoElemento;
 }else{
     lista->fim->prox=novoElemento;
     novoElemento->prox=NULL;
     lista->fim=novoElemento;
 }
}

void Imprimir(Lista*lista, char nome){
 ElementoLista*aux=lista->inicio;
  while(aux!=NULL){

    int i=0;
    for(i;(aux->nome[i])!='\0';i++){
        printf("%c",aux->nome[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");
  printf("p1= ");
  printf("%f\n",aux->p1);

  printf("p2= ");
  printf("%f\n",aux->p2);

  printf("p3= ");
  printf("%f\n",aux->p3);
  aux=aux->prox;
 }
}

int main(){
 Lista*lista=CriandoLista();
 float a=1.2,b=1.5,c=5.6;
 char aluno[81];
 printf("De o nome Da Pessoa ");
 scanf("%s", aluno);
 printf("Nome Da Pessoa %s \n", aluno);
 addElemento(lista,CriandoElemento(a,b,c,aluno));
 Imprimir(lista, aluno);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No topo do programa, faça

```
#include <string.h>
```

Depois troque o conteúdo de CopiarString para

```
void CopiarString(char* destino, char* origem)
{
    strcpy(destino, origem);
}
```

Tire o `&` do `scanf("%s", &nome)` porque `nome`, sozinha, já é um endereço de memória.

Não esqueça de desalocar a memória com `free()`, antes de terminar o programa!